# An interval that calls a function inside an object, which also calls a function inside that object

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this, setinterval

```
function airEngineJS (canvasArg, properties) {

    this.canvas = (canvasArg == "undefined")? trace("Failed to set up canvas for airEngineJS") : canvasArg;
    this.cameras = [];
    this.displayObjects = [];
    this.hudDisplayObjects = [];
    this.fps = (properties == "undefined" || properties.fps == "undefined")? 30 : properties.fps;

    if (properties == "undefined" || properties.autoinit == "undefined" || properties.autoinit == true){
      this.keyboard = new keyboardJS();
      this.keyboard.init();
      this.cameras.push(new airCameraJS(this));
    }
    this.enterframe = setInterval(this.intervalCaller, 1000/this.fps);
    trace("A new airEngineJS has been created");
  }
  airEngineJS.prototype = {
    intervalCaller : function () {
      this.mainLoop();
    },
    logic : function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.displayObjects.length; ++i){
        this.displayObjects[i].logic();
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < this.cameras.length; ++j){
        this.cameras[j].logic();
      }
    },
    render : function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.cameras.length; ++i){
        for (var j = 0; j < this.displayObjects.length; ++j){
          this.displayObjects[j].renderOn(this.cameras[i]);
        }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < this.hudDisplayObjects.length; ++i){
        this.hudDisplayObjects[i].renderOn(this.canvas);
      }
    },
    mainLoop : function () {
      this.logic();
      this.render();
    }
  }
```

The interval [this.enterframe = setInterval(this.intervalCaller, 1000/this.fps);] calls correctly (this.intervalCaller), but this tries to call (this.mainLoop()) in the DOM.

Any suggestions about how should I do it? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close over the actual function call like this:

```
var self = this;
this.enterframe = setInterval(function() {
    self.intervalCaller();
}, 1000/this.fps);
```

It first creates a reference to the new instance which is then used inside the closure passed to `setInterval`.

Comment: Something is wrong in my code, it stopped working... I'm trying to solve it, I'll tell you if that worked...

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín you can check out this fiddle if you want to verify the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qetAK/

Comment: I already made it work! It was a bizarre issue. I believe it worked just by changing <"> to <'> in an 'undefined' comparison. I'll check the link eitherway :)
The code worked perfectly. Thanks! I believe I understand it now :/ So, it was trying to execute in the DOM because the path/route was using 'this', and it was no longer inside the object it was, more or less? :|

Comment: oh, the fiddle is an example showing the code working. Nice :)

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín yes, the `setInterval` will call the function but will bind `this` to `window`; the closure prevents that